# MuseScore - Copy and paste

Tags: transposition, musescore

I have just started experimenting with MuseScore.  Nothing serious but it is proving to be a useful tool to explore and understand music.  I was entering some string parts and hit this odd problem. I had entered the cello part and wanted to copy it to the double bass.  So, I tried copy and paste.  It worked but the effect was not what I wanted.  It moved the notes up an octave so that the bass would play the same notes as the cello.  Of course, what I wanted was that it would be notated the same and hence the bass would play an octave below.  Is there a technique for this?

I can see the logic in what it did.  If I were to copy an oboe part to the clarinet then I would appreciate the transposition.  (I have not tried that yet.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, this is correct behaviour.  If you don't want a literal copy of the music, after the Copy/Paste leave the notes selected and call the Transpose function.  It will take just a couple of clicks to shift down an octave.

Comment: I had used transpose but I had not thought to try it on a single part.

Comment: In the case of an octave, you could also do shift+down arrow (I forgot the key combination but it is something like that)

Comment: Right after you paste, while the pasted notes are still selected, ctrl+down arrow will set the notes in the right octave, here.